# Kubernetes Namespace Stuck in 'Terminating'

Tags: namespace, kubernetes

I'm encountering an issue where a Kubernetes namespace is stuck in the 'Terminating' state. Running `kubectl get ns cattle-monitoring-system -o json|jq` produces error messages related to `custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1` and shows a `DiscoveryFailed` condition in the namespace status:

```bash
E1213 08:02:39.979034  953148 memcache.go:287] couldn't get resource list for custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
…
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "Namespace",
  …
  "status": {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "lastTransitionTime": "2023-12-12T14:53:40Z",
        "message": "Discovery failed for some groups, 1 failing: unable to retrieve the complete list of server APIs: custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request",
        "reason": "DiscoveryFailed",
        "status": "True",
        "type": "NamespaceDeletionDiscoveryFailure"
      },
      …
    ]
  }
}
```

**How can I resolve this issue to successfully delete the namespace?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is related to the Kubernetes API server's inability to discover the custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 API, which is blocking the namespace from terminating. Here are the steps to troubleshoot and resolve this:

##### Check for Associated APIService

Investigate if there's an APIService for custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1:

```bash
kubectl get apiservices.apiregistration.k8s.io -o json|jq  '.items[]|select(.metadata.name=="v1beta1.custom.metrics.k8s.io")'
```

Output should be something like

```bash
{
  "apiVersion": "apiregistration.k8s.io/v1",
  "kind": "APIService",
  ...
  "status": {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "message": "service/example-service in \"example-namespace\" is not present",
        "reason": "ServiceNotFound",
        "status": "False",
        "type": "Available"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

##### Verify No Active Components Related to APIService:

Issue the following command. Adjust `example-service` according to the output you generated earlier.

```bash
for c in configmaps secrets deployments statefulsets pods services; do
    echo "Checking for $c related to example-service"
    kubectl get $c -A | grep example-service
done
```

If there's no output, it confirms there are no active components related to the APIService in the cluster.

##### Delete the APIService

```bash
kubectl delete apiservice v1beta1.custom.metrics.k8s.io
```

After deleting the APIService, the namespace should proceed to terminate. Monitor the cluster for any unexpected issues.